# Button with first half transparent and other half title

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have some requirement to prepare a UI like Image 1:
[image]
But sometime i get it like(title disappeared)
[image]

I am not sure why this is happening.
The background image second has half transparent and half image(refresh image),there i need to show text.

**EDIT**
XIB settings:
[image]
[image]

Any idea or solution for this ?
**OR**
Please suggest some other way to achieve this.

Comment: you need to set left inset property for that button so that text clear will be after that gray arrows

Comment: What you want ? If You want to do as like image 1 ? then best way is create image with text "Clear" if it is fix otherwise put code of your button.

Comment: @iPatel The i need the title because the colour of the title will be configured from server.

Comment: @Arun_k check my comment it will help you.

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora I have already done it

Answer (score 0):

I just found in the `UIstoryboard`, why don't you try in this way

[image]
[image]

You can configure this UIButton as your need with the title attributes, right ?

Comment: Yes,title is configurable and depended on server for colour settings

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment => ***colour of the title will be configured from server.***

Then may be it is also possible that sometimes you will get **clearColor** of your button's title from server so you not able to display title of button. For solve this issue you need to put condition such like,

```
if(ButtonTitleColor is "clearColor")
  [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // here set color whatever you want.
```

Comment: Clear colour is not there as an option,Colour can be any thing other than clear colour

Comment: Yes,i think so,but some times i see title  and some times i don't see the title with the same setting in server(This case is very frequent).I'm using XIB for setting title and image.